# MySQL: Grouping results by perceptual hash similarity

Tags: mysql, sql, phash

Let's say we have MySQL table `Image` with following columns

- id
- user_id
- p_hash

I know how to calculate hamming distance (to reveal similar images) between newly inserted row's perceptual hash and all existing data in table. SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT `Image`.*, BIT_COUNT(`p_hash` ^ :hash) as `hamming_distance`
FROM `Image`
HAVING `hamming_distance` < 5
```

I want to do the same to every existing image.(to check if there are similar images in the database)
So, I have go through every row of the `Image` table, do the same process as above and find similar images from the table.

Now the question is, after whole procedure I want to get similar image groups only if elements of each group has at least one different `user_id` id?

So if, found group of similar images belongs to one user, then skip it. But if it belongs to multiple different users then return it as one of results.

Please help to figure out.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a self-join.

```
SELECT i1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(i2.id) AS similar_images
FROM Image AS i1
JOIN Image AS i2 ON i1.user_id != i2.user_id AND BIT_COUNT(i1.`p_hash` ^ i2.p_hash) < 5
GROUP BY i1.id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56d2e1/1)

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the OP was after, but a sample data set would doubt clarify the matter

Comment: How about skipping similar images if its belongs to same user? I need similars only if one of image belongs to one user, another one belongs to different user.

Comment: I changed query to query below but it doesn't return any result `SELECT i1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(i2.id) AS similar_images
FROM Image AS i1
JOIN Image AS i2 ON i1.id != i2.id AND i1.user_id != i2.user_id
AND BIT_COUNT(i1.`p_hash` ^ i2.p_hash) < 5
GROUP BY i1.id`

Comment: No need for `i1.id != i2.id` if the user IDs are different. But if I understand what you're looking for I think this should work. Are you sure you have images from different users whose hashes are similar? I don't think the datatype matters.

Comment: Can I apply this query also to p_hash column with bin(64) type? example values are: 1000000000000000000010100000000000101010000000000010101010000000

Comment: I don't see why it would make a difference.

Comment: Try modifying my sqlfiddle with 64-bit data and see what happens.

Comment: I did. It takes very long time: around 10 minutes. Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Probably not. It's comparing every row to almost every other row. There's no way to make use of indexes for something like this.

Comment: Here's an idea. Add another column containing the bit count of the hash, and index it (if you're using MySQL 5.7 or newer, this can be a generated column). Then you only need to test compare the hashes of rows that have similar bit counts. it might be able to use an index if you do `i1.hash_bit_count BETWEEN i2.hash_bit_count - 5 AND i2.hash_bit_count + 5`

Comment: and one more question: is perceptual hash applicable to icons also? or there are chances for mistake on icons

Comment: I don't know much about perceptual hash technology. But I guess with a small image, it only takes a few changes to distort it significantly, but this might not change the hash very much.